# Controller Edit - Inserindo Valores

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Meu método responsável pela edição está inserindo valores na tabela `CONSUL_EnciclopediasCONSUL_Promocoes`ao invés de editar.
Portando, se possuo as opções **x** com id=1 e **y** id=2 dentro do curso **a** com id=1 e originalmente escolho a opção **x**, minha tabela recebe 1 e 1. Se edito e agora escolho a opção **y**, minha tabela mantem o 1 e 1 e insere também o 1 e 2.

Domínio Enciclopédias

```
 public class CONSUL_Enciclopedias
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string Descricao { get; set; }
        public string PrazoEntrega { get; set; }
        public string Banner { get; set; }
        public string Foto { get; set; }
        public string LinkLoja { get; set; }
        public string DataEnvio { get; set; }
        public bool Ativo { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<CONSUL_Promocoes> Promocoes { get; set; }

    }
```

Domínio Promoções

```
public class CONSUL_Promocoes
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string Foto { get; set; }
        public string Descricao { get; set; }
        public bool Ativo { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<CONSUL_Enciclopedias> Enciclopedias { get; set; }

    }
```

Minha tabela `CONSUL_EnciclopediasCONSUL_Promocoes` recebe `CONSUL_Enciclopedias_ID` e também `CONSUL_Promocoes_ID`

Meu método de edição em meu Controller Enciclopedia

```
[CustomActionFilter]
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public PartialViewResult Edit(int id, CONSUL_Enciclopedias Enciclopedias, FormCollection collection)
{
    PromocoesAplicacao bdPromocoes;
    EnciclopediasAplicacao bdEnciclopedia;
    bdPromocoes = PromocoesAplicacaoConstrutor.PromocoesAplicacaoEF();
    bdEnciclopedia = EnciclopediasAplicacaoConstrutor.EnciclopediasAplicacaoEF();

    var enciclopedia = bdEnciclopedia.ListarPorId(id.ToString());
    var promoBD = bdPromocoes.ListarTodos();
    var listaCombo = new List<CONSUL_Promocoes>();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(collection["Promocoes"]))
    {
        var promos = collection["Promocoes"].ToString().Split(',');

        foreach (var promo in promos)
        {
            listaCombo.Add(promoBD.First(c => c.ID.ToString() == promo));
        }
    }

    Enciclopedias.Promocoes = listaCombo;
    bdEnciclopedias.Salvar(Enciclopedias);
    return null;
}
```

Repositorio

```
public class EnciclopediasRepositorioEF : IRepositorio<CONSUL_Enciclopedias>
{
    private readonly Contexto contexto;

    public EnciclopediasRepositorioEF()
    {
        contexto = new Contexto();
    }

    public void Salvar(CONSUL_Enciclopedias entidade)
    {
        if (entidade.ID > 0)
        {
            var EnciclopediasAlterar = contexto.Enciclopedias.First(x => x.ID == entidade.ID);
            EnciclopediasAlterar.PrazoEntrega = entidade.PrazoEntrega;
            EnciclopediasAlterar.Banner = entidade.Banner;
            EnciclopediasAlterar.Nome = entidade.Nome;
            EnciclopediasAlterar.Descricao = entidade.Descricao;
            EnciclopediasAlterar.Foto = entidade.Foto;
            EnciclopediasAlterar.LinkLoja = entidade.LinkLoja;
            EnciclopediasAlterar.Ativo = entidade.Ativo;
            EnciclopediasAlterar.DataEnvio = entidade.DataEnvio;
            EnciclopediasAlterar.CONSUL_Promocoes = entidade.CONSUL_Promocoes.Select(promo => contexto.Promocoes.FirstOrDefault(y => y.ID == promo.ID)).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            entidade.CONSUL_Promocoes.Select(promo => contexto.Promocoes.FirstOrDefault(y => y.ID == promo.ID)).ToList();
            contexto.Enciclopedias.Add(entidade);
        }
        contexto.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Excluir(CONSUL_Enciclopedias entidade)
    {
        var cartaAlterar = contexto.Enciclopedias.First(x => x.ID == entidade.ID);

        contexto.Set<CONSUL_Enciclopedias>().Remove(cartaAlterar);
        contexto.SaveChanges();
    }

    public IEnumerable<CONSUL_Enciclopedias> ListarTodos()
    {
        return contexto.Enciclopedias.Include(x => x.CONSUL_Promocoes).ToList();
    }

    public CONSUL_Enciclopedias ListarPorId(string id)
    {
        int idInt;
        Int32.TryParse(id, out idInt);
        return contexto.Enciclopedias.Include(x => x.CONSUL_Promocoes).FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == idInt);
    }
}
```

Comment: Você pode colocar também o código das suas classes de aplicação, por favor?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Claro, editei. Obrigado

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mais um exemplo do problema clássico do contexto destacado.

Quando você faz isso:

```
bdPromocoes = PromocoesAplicacaoConstrutor.PromocoesAplicacaoEF();
bdEnciclopedia = EnciclopediasAplicacaoConstrutor.EnciclopediasAplicacaoEF();
```

Você está criando dois contextos em separado, que não conhecem as informações que cada um monitora. Portanto, mesmo que o registro já exista, o contexto irá entender que é um registro novo.

Minha sugestão é instanciar o contexto no Controller e construir as classes de aplicação com ele:

```
public EnciclopediasRepositorioEF()
{
    contexto = new Contexto();
}

public EnciclopediasRepositorioEF(Contexto contexto)
{
    this.contexto = contexto;
}
```

E então:

```
var contexto = new Contexto();

bdPromocoes = PromocoesAplicacaoConstrutor.PromocoesAplicacaoEF(contexto);
bdEnciclopedia = EnciclopediasAplicacaoConstrutor.EnciclopediasAplicacaoEF(contexto);
```

Outro problema que considero é a sua modelagem. Você modelou assim:

```
public virtual ICollection<CONSUL_Enciclopedias> Enciclopedias { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<CONSUL_Promocoes> Promocoes { get; set; }
```

Isto não produz uma tabela associativa sozinho. Você precisa explicar pela *Fluent API* que existe essa associação (não sou muito fã dessa abordagem, pessoalmente falando), ou então modelar um *Model* extra que associe as duas (minha abordagem favorita):

```
public class EnciclopediaPromocao 
{
    [Key]
    public int EnciclopediaPromocaoId { get; set; }
    [Index("IUQ_EnciclopediaPromocao_EnciclopediaId_PromocaoId", IsUnique = true, Order = 1)]
    public int EnciclopediaId { get; set; }
    [Index("IUQ_EnciclopediaPromocao_EnciclopediaId_PromocaoId", IsUnique = true, Order = 2)]
    public int PromocaoId { get; set; }

    public virtual Enciclopedia Enciclopedia { get; set; }
    public virtual Promocao Promocao { get; set; }
}
```

E então alterar as associações nos dois *Models*, `Enciclopedia` e `Promocao`:

```
public virtual ICollection<EnciclopediaPromocao> EnciclopediaPromocoes { get; set; }
```

[`[Index]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.indexattribute(v=vs.113).aspx), introduzido nesta forma a partir do Entity Framework 6.1.0, garante a unicidade do registro associativo. Validações adicionais podem ser necessárias na aplicação para evitar erros estranhos de duplicidade de chave para o usuário.

Comment: Apenas uma dúvida. Alterei a linha `EnciclopediasAlterar.CONSUL_Promocoes = entidade.CONSUL_Promocoes.Select(promo => contexto.Promocoes.FirstOrDefault(y => y.ID == promo.ID)).ToList();` para             `EnciclopediasAlterar.CONSUL_Promocoes = contexto.Promocoes.ToList();` . Agora eu estou usando o mesmo contexto, porém, está dando o mesmo erro. Não era para ter ocorrido algo diferente?

Comment: Não. Isso não ocorreria se a modelagem estivesse correta. Pelo que eu entendi, você quer associar Enciclopédias com Promoções. Haveria de ter uma tabela associativa entre as duas (por exemplo `PromocoesEnciclopedia`) para que não sejam inseridas promoções em duplicadade. Precisa que eu coloque isso na resposta?

Comment: Poderia colocar por gentileza?

Comment: @RafaelBarbosa Feito.